# Mic input to the speaker output on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, speaker

How can I redirect the mic input to the speaker output on an iOS device? I know it feedbacks overtime, but how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from Apple. That does exactly what you want.

I.e. it plays the input directly out as it comes in.

Comment: I just tried that sample. It does play a little sound effect when one of the buttons is pressed, but it seems to be otherwise silent no matter what it's recording.