# Intercom with Bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, core-audio

I've been researching the ability to create a bi-directional audio link between iOS and a bluetooth audio headset.

What I need to be able to do is:
When the user speaks into the microphone on the iOS device, that audio should be redirected to the audio out of the headset, the piece.
When the microphone of the headset picks up audio, that should come out the speaker of the iOS device.

In my searching I've found that you can: 
Enable bluetooth audio input and output:
[how to route iPhone audio to the bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375837/how-to-route-iphone-audio-to-the-bluetooth-headset)

Redirect input to speaker:
[Mic input to the speaker output on an iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076850/mic-input-to-the-speaker-output-on-an-ios-device)

After reading this:
[AudioSession input from bluetooth output to line out or speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305986/audiosession-input-from-bluetooth-output-to-line-out-or-speaker)
I'm thinking what I want to do cannot be done.

So before I get to testing, does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.  From the last link it appears you can only have one input and output pair at a time.  What I'm trying to do would require two pairs of input and output.  In from BT, out to iOS speaker.  In from iOS Mic, out to BT.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current public iOS Audio Session APIs appear to only support a single audio route pair (input+output).