# Push-To-Talk (PTT) App using Bluetooth HFP between iPhone and Bluetooth device

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, hfp

We found PTT apps on iPhone store. Now I would like to make one for myself.
For the past 1 week, I have been reading all the posts here regarding how to achieve this in coding. Lets say, we paired the BTdevice with iPhone (The BTdevice supports HFP and A2DP).

1. When we make a call pressing the button on BTdevice to iPhone, in our iPhone app,
   we would like to recognize this EVENT or data in the app, then route the audio to iPhone-speaker.
2. When the button on the BTdevice released, user presses on-screen Button on iPhone to speak to BTdevice. The audio should be routed to BTdevice speaker.

Please through some procedure to achieve this in coding. Also libraries, classes and samples if available.

I understood this application can be achieved without MFi NDA with apple as HFP and A2DP are open in Apple ( I do understand the documentation available is limited).

I have found the following post EXACTLY addresses what I'm trying. Please take a look.

[Intercom with Bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239564/intercom-with-bluetooth-headset)

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been, and as your link indicates, pairing with Bluetooth connects the microphone and speaker of one device as dedicated input/output pair for another device, so you can't mix and match a microphone on one end with a speaker on the other.